# Netbeans Clean And Build Jar file returns "Could not find main class" on Win XP

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, classpath

I write a small java app and makes a jar file using Netbeans, it works fine on my windows 7 pc but doesn't work on Win XP. It returns "Could not find main class" error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Run your main class using `java -classpath . your_main_class_name` in Windows XP , Or re-build and run your application using NetBeans in Windows XP , the manifest file in the jar file might be be having a valid classpath for windows XP

Comment: I try and get "NoClassDefFoundClass" error. I try to run using "java -jar classname" and get "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError"